# Getting error :stream has already been operated upon or closed when I am using seperate streams

Tags: java

```
List<Employee_TechSol> empList=Employee_TechSol.getEmpList();
        System.out.println("Printing the stream----");
        Stream<Employee_TechSol> printStream=empList.stream();
        printStream.forEach(System.out::println);

        System.out.println("Filtering the stream----");
        Stream<Employee_TechSol> filterStream=empList.stream();
        filterStream.filter(emp->emp.getYearsInOrg()<17);
        filterStream.forEach(System.out::println); -- I am getting error here
```

Not sure why when I am using 2 streams seperately as printstream and filterstream. Am I forced to use supplier here?

Comment: you need to use return value of `filterStream.filter(emp->emp.getYearsInOrg()<17);`. you are using `filterStream` stream twice

Comment: @Nigel Thanks. Simply did not realised it. Used new stream object and it worked. Finally used chain of calls to combine it and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `filterStream.filter(emp->emp.getYearsInOrg()<17);`

This does not **change** filterStream, at all. It makes a new stream object that represents the notion of 'take the stream pointed at by the expression `filterStream`, then encapulse the notion of that stream, but filtered with the stated condition', and then returns that notion.

In other words, having a variable of type `Stream`, at all, is almost never what you want. The right approach is to chain the calls.

```
empList.stream()
  .filter(emp -> emp.getYearsInOrg() < 17)
  .forEach(System.out::println);
```

That's the standard 'style', and what you should be doing here.

Comment: I got it. If i use same approach, I have to create another stream object as

  System.out.println("Filtering the stream----");
        Stream<Employee_TechSol> filterStream=empList.stream();
        Stream<Employee_TechSol> empStream_filter = filterStream.filter(emp->emp.getYearsInOrg()<17);
        empStream_filter.forEach(System.out::println);

Corrected it to chain of calls by

 empList.stream().filter(emp->emp.getYearsInOrg()<17).sorted((emp1,emp2)->emp1.getEmpId()-emp2.getEmpId()).forEach(e->System.out.println(e.getEmpId()+" - "+e.getEmpName()));